# Can I remove a namespace import from a linqpad query?

Tags: namespaces, using, linqpad

I am trying to run a linqpad query, but one of the default namespace imports has a type that is apparently shadowing the type I am trying to reference.  `System.Xml` is one of the default imports in linqpad, but I rarely use it.  Is it possible to remove that default namespace import, so I can use my own `Formatting` enum?

Comment: Also, in my testing, it looks like the locally declared `Formatting` enum shadows the `System.Xml` enum. Intellisense even auto-completes with the local enum values.

Comment: @JesanFafon: My `Formatting` is not declared inside my query, but rather included as part of another import.  In fact, I think there may have been something wrong with my original query, because when I try to run it now, instead of getting that shadowing behavior, it fails to compile with this. `'Formatting' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Xml.Formatting' and 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your immediate question, but you can can tell LINQPad which one you want `Formatting` to mean. In your query, press the `F4` key and then under the Additional Namespace Imports tab you can add the following:

```
Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting
```

This tells LINQPad to declare a [using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) for your script. Note that you should not include the word `using` before the line, LINQPad handles theat for you.

Comment: I didn't realize you could refer to specific types with namespace aliases.  I thought those were only for namespaces.  That's pretty sweet.

Comment: Only reason I knew you could is because I've had the 'ambiguous reference' error in my code in Visual Studio before and Resharper fixes the issue when you tell it by creating a using alias for the type I want - took a guess that you could stick those statements into LINQPad as well and guessed correctly.